# How to pass my javascript string in ruby code

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I need to pass a string containing url to my ruby code through javascript. This code is written inside a javascript function.

```
   for(var u=0;u<universities.length;u++)
        {
            var myurl = String(universities[u]); //my javascript string containing a url
            <%
                require 'Nokogiri'
                require 'open-uri'
                html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(myurl))//want to get title of that url
                @hero = html.title
            %>
            names.push("<%=@hero%>");

        }
    alert(names);
```

Comment: You could use ajax, to post the names variable, but you would need an end-point to post to. You say ruby, but are you using rails?

Comment: Yes I am using rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately what you're looking at is that you probably want is to build the data-set in JavaScript and put the data-set into a hidden field and then submit them to the backend using your hidden field in the form.

So with more information I would be able to help you out more, but the breadcrumbs are that you make a form on the same page of this javascript and you have a hidden field like below:

```
<%= form_for mymodel do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :universities } %>
  <%= f.submit "Done id: "create-university" %>
<% end %>
```

And then at the end of your javascript just add the following instead of the alert you have:

```
$("#mymodel_universities").val(names);
```

However, you must keep track of the fact that `mymodel` is whatever your model on the backend that you want to update is, and that `universities` the field in the `mymodel` model that you want to update. Don't forget to update that in the form and the JavaScript.

Comment: This is a complicated way, my code works if I put a hard coded url string instead of myurl variable in the following line
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(myurl))
i just want to use a variable here which i can update though my javascript variable.

Comment: You want to get it from the front end to the backend into your controller through the view? You can only do it this way and using ajax, but the only example I have of ajax is with CoffeeScript and React.

Comment: Why can i simply access a ruby variable in javascript but can't access a javascript variable in ruby?

Comment: Well you can access the variables you put in your view using your controller. You cannot access the JavaScript variable in ruby unless you push it to your backend.

Comment: how can I push it to the backend then?

Comment: I have my controller file

Comment: your controller IS part of the backend. you need to submit the data from the client side using either a hidden form or ajax.

Comment: can i directly get data from html input field into my controller file, then process it and send it to my javascript?